# How to create a simple count-up timer (stopwatch) in JS using Date()?

Tags: javascript, html, timer

I've looked through a lot of examples for a simple stopwatch but most seem needlessly complicated or they use the `setInterval` function.

What is the most efficient way to create a simple timer (in raw JavaScript) that has a start/pause option, displays hours:mins:secs and uses the Date.now instead of setInterval/setTimeout?

Comment: Erm `setInterval()` is the way to do it - you need a callback to perform the UI update. Whats the problem with it?

Comment: @AlexK. `setInterval() ` can lead to a few hiccups and problems while executing your code. Using date is much more efficient and safe. Unfortunately I don't know how to. :P https://zetafleet.com/blog/2010/04/why-i-consider-setinterval-to-be-harmful.html

Comment: For a simple timer there are no "network latency" issues nor the reasonable expectation of an unanticipated error.

Comment: @AlexK. I agree, however I'd like to learn to make a timer using the Date instead of setInterval for my particular code

Comment: You cannot use a Date alone, you need a timer to fire off your code that actually does something; like updating the UI.

Comment: @AlexK. Would really appreciate if you could write a sample code or link me to one.

Comment: Date.doCountUpTimerStopwatch()

Comment: `setInterval(() => document.body.innerHTML = new Date(), 1000)` - there we go.